# html Agility pack is getting source of first web page only

Tags: parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

i want to crawl an e commerce website using Html agility pack but i am having an issue the html agility pack is getting source of front web page only because when i try to get the source of inner or sub items in that website i am not having that bunch of code in the source that i get from html agility pack.when i click on items then i can see code of submenu items through firebug but not in the actual source that i have.so please guide me or tell me what to do

```
string url=""; 
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/45.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36";
                html = client.DownloadString(url);
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

through this code using html agility pack i can only have code of first web page

Answer (score 0):

tested this, it gets the code of the whole website against particular URL